# enable Process menu in On premise TFS

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs

I was previously using Team Foundation services free account on the cloud with my Hotmail account. Now I am try to install TFS on a server computer. Everything worked fine. But then I noticed that I dont see the "Process" Menu option in my on Premise TFS account, while this shows up in the other account.

So, how can I enable "Process" menu option in my On Premise TFS web portal? So that I can configure the Work Item types and the process.

Below is my snapshot of my cloud account that does have the "Process" menu option.

[image: Cloud account with Process menu option]

While here is the image of On Premises account that has a very simple menu option.

[image: On Premise account with simple menu option]

Answer (score 0):

The **Process** option menu only shows in Team Services (the cloud), there isn’t this option in On-Premises TFS web portal.

If you work in an on-premises TFS, and want to customize a process template, 
you can download the zipped template file using the **Process Template Manager**. You'll need to use a version of Visual Studio that is at the same version level as TFS. You can install the latest version of **Visual Studio Community** for free.
Please see [Upload or download a process template](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/work/guidance/manage-process-templates) and Customize a process template for details.

To configure the Work Item types and the process please see [Add or modify a work item type.](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/work/customize/add-modify-wit)